# MongoDB - Find where list of nested documents has more than one field with a value greater than 0

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of `User` documents with the following shape:

```
// User

{
  payments: [
    { total: number }, 
  ],
}
```

The `payments` array of nested documents of variable length contains number `totals` with values equal to or greater than 0.

How do I find a list of `Users` where the length of `payments` with `total > 0` is greater than one?

For example, I want to find documents like these:

```
// two totals > 0 
{
  payments: [
    { total: 50 }, 
    { total: 50 },
  ],
}
// two totals > 0 
{
  payments: [
    { total: 50 },
    { total: 0 },
    { total: 50 },
  ],
}
// three totals > 0 
{
  payments: [
    { total: 50 },
    { total: 50 }, 
    { total: 0 }, 
    { total: 50 }, 
  ],
}
```

but not these documents:

```
// not enough totals > 0 
{
  payments: [
    { total: 50 }, 
    { total: 0 },
    { total: 0 }, 
  ],
}
// not enough totals > 0 
{
  payments: [
    { total: 0 },
    { total: 0 }, 
  ],
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/AG8Q1GqSEcl

You have to use an aggregation query.

[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) array where the total is greater than 0 and get the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of filtered array. Check if it's greater than 1 [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      payments: "$payments",
      paymentsGreaterThanZero: {
        $size: {
          $filter: { input: "$payments", as: "item", cond: { $gt: [ "$$item.total",0 ] } }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { paymentsGreaterThanZero: { $gt: 1 } } },
  { $project: { payments: "$payments" } }
])
```